# Error: unable to open database in macOS Mojave

Tags: terminal, mojave

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Mail/V6/MailData/Envelope\ Index vacuum;
Error: unable to open database "/Users/Me/Library/Mail/V6/MailData/Envelope Index": 
unable to open database file
```

This happened after upgrading to Mojave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this issue and solved it before posting the question. I was also having other quirky permissions issues within Terminal after upgrading to Mojave.

I stumbled upon this and thought I would share here, since I don't normally consult the more casual Mac user pages: [Fix Terminal “Operation not permitted” Error in MacOS Mojave](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/)

Basically, you need to add Terminal.app to have Full Disk Access within System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab.

Comment: Please don't just give a link as it will change but put the information in the answer. The link can be left for attribution and also if it has more information.

Comment: People are absolutely *fascinated* with these "punch great big holes in the OS" sort of posts, while at the same time absolutely *frothing* at the mouth about insert_evil_corporation and security.